# how can i change the image for collapsible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
         <div class="ui-block-a" data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d">
            <h3>collapsible</h3>
            <p>This ddis a way.</p>
        </div>
```

I am using jquery mobiles 1.4.2 I want you use my own image for collapse when it is expanded and collapsed.I want to remove the border.

Comment: Are you familiar with your browser's DOM inspector? It's trivial to find out where the image is stored and either replace it or do an override with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom icon to jQuery Mobile via CSS (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/icons/):

Substitute myicon with the icon name you want to use.

```
.ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("iconimg.svg");
}
/* Fallback */
.ui-nosvg .ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("iconimg.png");
}
```

Then in the collapsible you can use `data-collapsed-icon` and `data-expanded-icon` and assign them to the icons you created.

To remove the border from the content:

```
.ui-collapsible-content{
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

To remove the border from the header:

```
.ui-collapsible-heading a {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

If you want a plain icon without the disk behind it add the classes `ui-alt-icon` and `ui-nodisc-icon` to the collapsible div.